# How to use WeakReferenceMessenger in MAUI?

Tags: maui

I didn't get a clear picture of how to use `WeakReferenceMessenger` in MAUI after reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger) blog.

I am using `MessagingCenter` in my xamarin forms app like below.

```
//Send message
MessagingCenter.Send<ModePage>(this, "modechanged");

//Subscribe message and actions
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ModePage>(this, "modechanged", (sender) =>
{
    SetMode();
});
```

Please show me the equivalent usage of the above code using `WeakReferenceMessenger`? In `WeakReferenceMessenger` where I need to pass the key and to subscribe with key?

Comment: you have to define a type that inherits from `RequestMessage<T>` instead of just defining `string` message keys

Comment: I decided to write a quick guide on Messengers and their usage with .NET https://medium.com/@freakyali/messengers-api-in-net-73ce3382008d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MessagingCenter` has been deprecated in .NET 7 and replaced with `WeakReferenceMessenger` in the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm) NuGet package.

Below are the detailed steps on how to use `WeakReferenceMessenger` in MAUI:

1. Install the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm) NuGet package into your project.
2. Define a message class: SendItemMessage.cs that you want to send across different parts or pages of your MAUI app like below:

```
public class SendItemMessage : ValueChangedMessage<string> 
{
    public SendItemMessage(string value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}
```

3. Sending the messages:
   You need to pass an instance of the message class to the `Send` method like below:

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new SendItemMessage("Model Changed"));
```

4. Receiving the messages:
   You need to register a message handler for the message class like below:

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<SendItemMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
{

     OnMessageReceived(m.Value);
});
```

Here's the sample code below for your reference:

**MainPage.cs:**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{
      public MainPage(MainPageViewModel viewModel)
      {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = viewModel;
      }

      private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new SendItemMessage("Model Changed"));
      }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
      <Button 
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs:**

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
        public  MainPageViewModel()      
        {
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<SendItemMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
            {
                OnMessageReceived(m.Value);
            });            
        }

        private static void OnMessageReceived(string value)
        {
            Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Messages received", value, "OK");
        }
}
```

Another cool way to register message handlers by using the `IRecipient<TMessage>` interface to register message handlers.

```
public class MainPageViewModel: IRecipient<SendItemMessage> 
{
        public  MainPageViewModel()            
        {

            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register(this);  
        }

        public void Receive(SendItemMessage message)
        {
            Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Messages received", message.Value, "OK");
         }


    }
```

**Update:**

```
public class SendItemMessage : ValueChangedMessage<string> 
{
    public SendItemMessage(string value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}
```

The `ValueChangedMessage<T>` class is a generic class that represents a message that contains a value of type `T` that has been changed. Since the SendItemMessage implements the `ValueChangedMessage<string>`, the generic parameter  specifies the type of the value that the message carries. In the example above, the value is a string. You can define the type of the value according to your own design like simple datatype:`int` ,`bool` or even class model etc.

Comment: Like `SendItemMessage` should I create different classes for next `WeakReferenceMessenger`? If I want to pass a value other than a string value, I need to change the below code with that datatype, right? `public SendItemMessage(string value) : base(value)`

Comment: 1.Yes, you can create different message class according to your own design. 2.See my update in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you want. As Jason said you need a message to invoke. So all of this can look like this.

**Register Message**

```cs
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default
    .Register<ModekMessage>(
    this,
    (recipient, message) =>
    {
        if (message.Value == true)
        {
            SetMode(true);
        }
        else 
        {
           SetMode(false);
        }
    });
```

A message is needed to signal change.

```cs
public class ModekMessage : ValueChangedMessage<bool>
{
    public ModekMessage(bool modeChanged) : base(modeChanged)
    {
    }
}
```

We also need to do some garbage collection for this

```cs
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();

    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default
        .Unregister<ModekMessage>(this);
}
```

**Sending message**

```cs
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new ModekMessage(true));
```

**Alternative**

Let me also give an alternative to this. This is perhaps more common scenario, than using `WeakReferenceMessenger`

If you have a control that you need to communicate that it changing mode.

**Control**

The control implement an event that your page can listen to.

```cs
public event EventHandler<ModeChangedEventArgs> ModeChanged;
```

We need an Event Message arguments.

```cs
public class ModeChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ModeChangedEventArgs(Mode mode)
    {
        Mode = mode;
    }

    public Mode Mode { get;  }
}
```

We need some property so we can go set and read. As you can see we Invoke the event here, to tell whoever is listening that a mode change has happened.

```cs
private Mode _mode;

public Mode Mode
{
    get => _mode;
    set
    {
        _mode = value;
        Update();
        ModeChanged?.Invoke(this, new ModeChangedEventArgs(value));
    }
}
```

Now we can expose public methods, and in one go we send our event:

```cs
public void Pause() => Mode= Mode.Paused;

public void Start() => Mode = Mode.Started;
```

**The View**

In your view you listen to the event like this

```cs
control.ModeChanged += OnModeChange;
```

With an event handler

```cs
private void OnModeChange(object sender, ModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Mode)
    {
        case Mode.Started:
            break;
        case Mode.Paused:
            break;
        case Mode.Reset:
            break;
        case Mode.Stopped:
            break;
        case Mode.Finnish:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you need to use `WeakReferenceMessenger` inside a static class, you can't use `this`. Instead try this solution.
At the top of your class create a variable that will reference the static class (where "MyClassName" is the name of your static class). I always call this variable `me`:

```
private static Type me = typeof(MyClassName);
```

Then when registering use:

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<MessageToListenFor>(me, (r, m) => ProcessNewValue(m.Value));
```

Also, as good practice, I recommend always checking if the message has been previously registered:

```
    if(!WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.IsRegistered<MessageToListenFor>(me)) 
    {
         WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<MessageToListenFor>(me, (r, m) => ProcessNewValue(m.Value));
    }
```