# How can i Update Appshell.xaml In Maui

Tags: maui

THIS IS SOME OF CODE IN MY APPSHELL.XAML

```
  <FlyoutItem Title="Speech To Text" IsEnabled="False"
           Icon="lock.jfif">
      <Tab>
          <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AllNotesPage}" />
      </Tab>
  </FlyoutItem>
```

THIS IS SOME OF MY CODE FROM ACTIVITY CALLED NOTEPAGE.XAML.CS

```
 private async void SaveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (BindingContext is Models.Note note)
         File.WriteAllText(note.Filename, TextEditor.Text);

     await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
 }

  private void LoadNote(string fileName)
  {
      Models.Note noteModel = new Models.Note();
      noteModel.Filename = fileName;

      if (File.Exists(fileName))
      {
          noteModel.Date = File.GetCreationTime(fileName);
          noteModel.Text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
      }

      BindingContext = noteModel;
  }
```

SO BASICALLY I WANNA DO LIKE WHEN TEXT LIKE "iNotesx" SAVED OR EXIST IN NOTES THAN
IT WILL AUTOMATICALLY ENABLE THAT FlyoutItem "Speech To Text" THAT I DISABLED BY DEFAULT IN APPSHELL.XAML IS THIS POSSIBLE? in .net 7.0

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `WeakReferenceMessenger` in the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm) NuGet package to dynamically change the `IsEnabled` property of `<FlyoutItem>` to true if the condition is met.

Firstly, you could add a name to `<FlyoutItem>`.

```
<FlyoutItem x:Name="allNotesPage"  Title="Speech To Text" IsEnabled="False"
           Icon="dotnet_bot">
      <Tab>
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AllNotesPage}" />
      </Tab>
 </FlyoutItem>
```

And then open the `AppShell.xaml.cs`, add following code. If we want to enable the `FlyoutItem`, just send a message to set `allNotesPage.IsEnabled` to `true`.

```
public AppShell()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<string>(this, (r, m) =>
        {
             MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
             {
                 // Code to run on the main thread
                 allNotesPage.IsEnabled = true;
             });
           
       });
}
```

Finally, open the **NotePage.xaml.cs**, send a message to enable the target `FlyoutItem`.

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send("OneMessage");
```

You can refer to [How to use WeakReferenceMessenger in MAUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77093856/9644964) on how to use `WeakReferenceMessenger`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes This is Possible

step - 1: Check if the text "iNotesx" is Exist in saved note

```
 bool trtTextPresent = note.Text.Contains("iNotesx");
```

Step - 2: Get the "Speech To Text" FlyoutItem From Shell
using some LINQ

```
var speechToTextItem = (FlyoutItem)Shell.Current.Items.FirstOrDefault(item =>
     item is FlyoutItem && ((FlyoutItem)item).Title == "Speech To Text");
```

Step - 3 : Now Just  enable it by simply using "IsEnabled"

```
  if (speechToTextItem != null)
  {
      speechToTextItem.IsEnabled = trtTextPresent;
  }
```